# android:layout_alignParentTop="true" and android:layout_centerVertical="true" do not set the imageView centered at the the top of the screen

Tags: java, android, xml, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

I have a very simple layout where I'm attempting to center an imageView in the middle of the screen but aligned to the top. I've attempted to use the following however it does not seem to be working and im unsure why: the imageView appears in the upper left hand corner instead of being centered and aligned to the top.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

> I'm attempting to center an imageView in the middle of the screen but aligned to the top..

Use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` instead of `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` in the `ImageView`. So following should be your XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/backspace_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Indeed, the android:layout_alignParentTop="true" is not necessary, it's aligned to parent's top as default.